# loop a function in jquery

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm making a game. I want to create rounds.
My script do this:

```
var rounds = 10;
var currentround = 1;
$('.go').click(function () {
    $("#start").fadeOut(); //HIDE A CONFIG DIV
    beforegame(); //LOAD EFFECT BEFORE GAME
    $("#gametab").fadeIn();//Fade in my game tab
    gametabloop();
});

function gametabloop(){
    do   {
        checking();//check who and when win
        if (checking()==true) 
        { 
            nextround()// call nextround (update points showing, and clear game divs)
            $("#gametab").delay(300).fadeIn(10); //Show game tab one more time
            current_round++;
        }
    }
    while (currentround>=rounds);
    showtheend();//after all rounds call this function

}
}
```

It doesn't work. I have no errors, but when I'm playing, and when round is finished nothing actually happens

Comment: try changing `while (currentround>=rounds)` to `while(currentround<=rounds)`. I also see a `current_round` variable that is not defined within your given code.

Comment: is your `checking` function supposed to return a boolean? And why are you calling it twice in a row (before and inside the `if`)? What does `nextRound` do? You did not provide enough code to accurately assist you.

Comment: Is `current_round++` a typo for `currentround++`?

Comment: Note that a Javascript loop can't wait for asynchronous user interaction. So it can't wait for the user to fill in a form or click on things, only for synchronous calls like `prompt()`.